# Making an API call through ReactJs, fetch JSON and display in ag-grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

EDIT:
I have experimented around the code. The modified code is given below.
    Now I get an error "TypeError: rowData.forEach is not a function" in the browser.
      When I console log, enter image description here it is showing the JSON arrays (I have attached a screenshot).
       I think the problem is something to do with JSON object not getting converted to an array. Can someone experienced, please help?

MODIFIED CODE

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css';
//import {Grid} from '@ag-grid-community/all-modules';

class App extends Component {
  constructor (props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      isLoaded: true,
      columnDefs: [{
      headerName: "Id", field: "id"
    }, {
      headerName: "Name", field: "name"
    }, {
      headerName: "Description", field: "description"
    }, {
      headerName: "Price", field: "price"
    },
    {
      headerName: "Firm Name", field: "category_id"
    },
    {
      headerName: "Amount", field: "category_name"
    }
    ],
    rowData: []
  };

  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
        console.log ("entered");
    fetch("http://localhost/api/product/read.php")
      .then (res => res.json() )
      //.then ((result) => {this.setState({rowData: result, isLoaded: true})},
        .then(rowData => this.setState({rowData}),
        (error) => {
          console.log("error");
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: false,
            error

          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    const {error,isLoaded,rowData } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } 
    else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } 
    else {
      console.log({rowData});
      return (
        <div
        className="ag-theme-balham"
        style={
          {
        height: '800px',
        width: '1200px' }
      }
      >
        <AgGridReact
          columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
          rowData={this.state.rowData}
          >
        </AgGridReact>
      </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have been trying to call an API from reactjs.I have tried fetch,jquery and apiox codes but I am getting an error. I actually want to call an external URL from one of our other software but since it is not working, I have created a php file on localhost and tried calling that file.In each case it is printing "entered" and then "error" to console.
             Both the external api file and the localhost file, when tried in the browser are returning JSON objects.
        PLease see code below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css';

class ListOrders extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      columnDefs: [{
        headerName: "Invoice No", field: "id"
      }, {
        headerName: "Invoice Date", field: "name"
      }, {
        headerName: "Payer Name", field: "description"
      }, {
        headerNAme: "Ship To Name", field: "price"
      },
      {
        headerNAme: "Firm Name", field: "category_id"
      },
      {
        headerNAme: "Amount", field: "category_name"
      }
      ],
      rowData: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
    console.log ("entered");
    fetch("http://localhost/api/product/read.php",{
      mode: "no-cors", 
    method: 'GET', // or 'PUT'
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
     // body: JSON.stringify(),
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(
        (response) => {
          console.log("result");
           this.setState( {

            rowData: response.JSON
      //console.log(rowData)
         });
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log("error");
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error

          });
        }
      )
  }



  render()
   {
    return (
      <div
        className="ag-theme-balham"
        style={
          {
        height: '800px',
        width: '1200px' }
      }
      >
        <AgGridReact
          columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
          rowData={this.state.rowData}>
        </AgGridReact>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ListOrders ;
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: you should have a .catch() after your last .then().  Probably won't solve the problem, but it should give you a better error.

Comment: The error is the "error" string that I have printed in console.log.  It just means that the program is entering the error loop after it has console logged the "entered" string.

Comment: your rowdata needs to be an array. The error suggests that it is not an array. Instead of posting the entire code, can you post only the relevant section and the output from your api call?